# How get list transactions for my HD account to json

Tags: blockchain

How get list of transactions with all my btc addresses with HD account to json format. PHP. I need in link for it

```
$json_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/merchant/$guid/accounts/0?password=$pass";   
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: What does HD stand for?

Comment: HD (Hierarchical Deterministic) Wallet
https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3/blob/6ce5af7acd5e654470d13bff4bb6815e77d949db/README.md#enable-hd-functionality